# Setting Autoincrement in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was in my designer trying to enable the auto increment and when trying to save the changes this error shows, I am using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.

[image]

Does anyone know why? Thank You.

Comment: go to Tools => Options => Designers => uncheck "Prevent saving changes ....". try this one first

Comment: Thank you I knew it was something small. @mihirshah

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a feature in Management Studio that prevents you from accidentally dropping and re-creating a table without knowing it.  You can turn this off in Tools -> Options -> Designers -> "Table and Database Designers" - Option is "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation".

You should turn this off with caution as this feature is trying to help prevent you from causing issues.  I recommend you only do this against development servers, or even better always just generate the script and execute that instead.  This way you will always know what commands are being executed.